# Grid with larger first item in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to achieve this view with jetpack compose:

[image]

I create a row consisting of an image with a weight 0.7 and a column that contains those smaller images with a weight 0.3.
But there is always padding at bottom of the column and they won't align perfectly.
My code:

```
@Composable
fun TrendingSection() {
    Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.shadmehr),
            contentDescription = "First trending music",
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(0.7f)
                .padding(4.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
        )
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(0.3f)
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.shadmehr),
                contentDescription = "First trending music",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(4.dp)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
            )
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.shadmehr),
                contentDescription = "First trending music",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(4.dp)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone knows what is the problem or know a better solution for doing this?

Result:
[image]

Comment: You just have wrong weights, use `weight(2f)` and `weight(1f)`

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Yes, tnx dude :)